# How to start a docker container inside the setup?

Tags: docker, go, continuous-integration, drone.io

I have created a DroneCI pipeline with the following content:

```
kind: pipeline
type: docker
name: Build auto git tagger

steps:
  - name: test and build
    image: golang
    commands:
      - go mod download
      - go test ./test
      - go build -o ./build/package ./cmd/git-tagger

  - name: Build docker image
    image: plugins/docker
    pull: if-not-exists
    settings:
      username: 
      password: 
      repo: 
      dockerfile: 
      registry: 
      auto_tag: 

trigger:
  branch:
    - master
```

The `go test` starts a gogs docker container for testing purpose, here is the code:

```
func createGogsContainer(dest, waitUrl string) (stopContainer, error) {
    client, err := docker.NewClientFromEnv()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    ctx := context.Background()

    gogs, err := client.CreateContainer(docker.CreateContainerOptions{
        Name: "repo",
        Config: &docker.Config{
            Image: "gogs/gogs",
        },
        HostConfig: &docker.HostConfig{
            PublishAllPorts: true,
            AutoRemove:      true,
            Mounts: []docker.HostMount{
                {
                    Type:   "bind",
                    Source: dest,
                    Target: "/data",
                }},
            PortBindings: map[docker.Port][]docker.PortBinding{
                "3000/tcp": {{HostIP: "0.0.0.0", HostPort: "8888"}},
                "22/tcp":   {{HostIP: "0.0.0.0", HostPort: "2222"}},
            },
        },
        Context: ctx,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = client.StartContainer(gogs.ID, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    //Wait for connection
    host, err := url.Parse(waitUrl)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    err = waitHTTP(fmt.Sprintf("%s://%s", host.Scheme, host.Host), 3, 0)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return func() error {
        return client.StopContainerWithContext(gogs.ID, 5, ctx)
    }, nil
}
```

The pipeline has been aborted with following error message:

```
latest: Pulling from library/golang
Digest: sha256:f30b0d05ea7783131d84deea3b5f4d418d9d930dfa3668a9a5fa253d1f9dce5a
Status: Image is up to date for golang:latest
+ go mod download
+ go test ./test
time="2020-04-23T17:58:24Z" level=error msg="Get \"http://0.0.0.0:8888/gat/WithoutTag.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack\": dial tcp 0.0.0.0:8888: connect: connection refused"
time="2020-04-23T17:58:24Z" level=error msg="Get \"http://0.0.0.0:8888/gat/WithoutTag.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack\": dial tcp 0.0.0.0:8888: connect: connection refused"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is a special IPv4 address that means "everywhere"; it doesn't usually make sense to include it in a URL.  I don't know off hand how `net/http` treats it.  You also just might not be waiting long enough for the container to be ready.

Comment: @DavidMaze What do you suggest I should do?

Comment: If this test driver isn't itself running in a container, and Docker isn't running in a VM, you can probably use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` as the host part of the URL.  It's not clear what the parameters to `waitHTTP` are but you also might need more retries or longer delay between retries.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Drone services.](https://docs.drone.io/pipeline/docker/syntax/services/) It allows you to bring up a container as part of your pipeline and access its ports.

In your case you can bring up the Gogs container like this:

```
services:
- name: gogs
  image: gogs/gogs
```

And then use it like this in your pipeline steps:

```
steps:
  - name: test and build
    image: golang
    commands:
      - curl "http://gogs"
      -
...
```

(this assumes the `gogs` container listens on port 80. If it's a different port then you need to adjust the URI).

Hint: the name of the service is the DNS name of the container.